# полигоны яндекс карт в json_encode

Tags: php, json, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

есть код:

```
$json_data = array("type"=>"Feature", 
        "id"=>$arItem['ID'], 
        "geometry"=>array(
        "type"=>"Polygon", 
        "coordinates"=>[$coords]),
        "properties"=>array(
            "balloonContentHeader"=>"".$arItem['NAME']."",
            "balloonContentBody"=>"",
            "balloonContentFooter"=>"",
            "hintContent"=>"".$arItem['NAME']."",
            "type"=>"".$arItem['PROPERTY_TYPE_POINT_ENUM_ID']."")
        );
        $encode_data = json_encode($json_data);
```

Формирует json под objectmanager яндекс карт для вывода полигонов из базы данных.
На выходе получаем:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type":"Feature","id":"279","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":["[["48.735550","44.496452"],["48.741000","44.496795"],["48.743498","44.507095"],["48.741681","44.516365"],["48.740773","44.521171"],["48.737821","44.524948"],["48.731008","44.522888"],["48.727147","44.513962"],["48.726920","44.504349"],["48.727828","44.498855"],["48.735550","44.496452"]]"]},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"\u041f\u043b\u043e\u0449\u0430\u0434\u043a\u0430 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0435","balloonContentBody":"","balloonContentFooter":"","hintContent":"\u041f\u043b\u043e\u0449\u0430\u0434\u043a\u0430 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440\u0435","type":"1"}}]}
```

Но полигоны не выводятся т.к coordinates":[" берутся в кавычки, а по правилам objectmanager координаты полигонов должны быть значением без кавычек в json. И должно получиться вот так:

```
"coordinates":[[["48.735550","44.496452"],["48.741000","44.496795"],["48.743498","44.507095"],["48.741681","44.516365"],["48.740773","44.521171"],["48.737821","44.524948"],["48.731008","44.522888"],["48.727147","44.513962"],["48.726920","44.504349"],["48.727828","44.498855"],["48.735550","44.496452"]]]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы json_encode не добавлял кавычки в значение coordinates?

Comment: Как вы формируете `$coords`? у вас он строка, если делать массивом вещественных чисел, то конвертирует все нормально: `$coords=array(array(48.735550,44.496452),array(48.741000,44.496795));` выводит `"coordinates":[[48.73555,44.496452],[48.741,44.496795]]`

Comment: переменную формирую $coords = $arItem['PROPERTY_COORDS_S_VALUE']; она получает значение из бд, и находится в цикле while

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть этот цикл, у вас там формируется строка, а нужен массив, если в базе хранится именно строка с координатами, надо ее разбивать на отдельные значения и формировать массив, который уже и передавать в `$coords`